# SQL Query to 'ORDER BY' on 3 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the below table (Raw Table), I need to run a query so that everything is sorted to mirror the Result Table. I have tried using ORDER BY to do this and I can get the first 2 requirements to work (see order by requirements) but the 3rd one is where I'm getting lost.

Right now, my query is as follows:

```
sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Identifier = @identifier AND Flag <> 'DELETED' ORDER BY Status DESC,  Number * 1";
```

I have been reading into using a `ORDER BY CASE WHEN...THEN...END` but I'm not understanding the syntax correctly. I keep getting syntax errors so I'm not even able to run it.

ORDER BY Requirement:

1. Order the status column with 'open' values at top, 'closed' values
   at bottom (this is working)
2. Order the Number column to be sequential (with closed at bottom,
   open at top for the Status column) (this is working)
3. Order the Flag column so that null values are at the top and
   anything else is at the bottom (above Status closed sort)

From what I can tell, the `ORDER BY CASE` is what I want, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

**RAW TABLE**

```
| Flag | Number | Status |
|------------------------|
| a    |    1   |  open  |
|      |    5   |  open  |
|      |    3   | closed |
| a    |    4   |  open  |
| a    |    2   | closed |
```

**RESULT TABLE**

```
| Flag | Number | Status |
|------------------------|
|  a   |    1   |  open  |
|  a   |    4   |  open  |
|      |    5   |  open  |
|      |    3   | closed |
|  a   |    2   | closed |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Questions
WHERE Identifier = @identifier AND Flag <> 'DELETED' 
ORDER BY Status DESC,  Number,
(case when flag is null then 1 else 0 end) desc, flag
```

You can try this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Testing out your query right now. It seems to be doing everything except putting the null values in Flag at the top. Doing some more testing to see what the issue is.

Comment: if you want `null` values to be shown first, change the ordering in the `order by` clause.

Comment: Yea, but when I do that, it ignores the ordering of question and status fields. Still looking...

Comment: Almost there. `ORDER BY Status DESC,
(CASE WHEN Flag is null then 1 else 0 end) ASC, flag, [QNumber] * 1` works but the Flag column that has values only wants to be at the bottom, not the top like I need it. I'm guessing I need to rearrange the query a little bit more.

Comment: use `flag desc` in that case

Comment: That was it! Thanks! (God, I love SOF)

Answer (score 2):

Using nested `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Questions
--WHERE Identifier = @identifier AND Flag <> 'DELETED' 
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Status = 'Open' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    Number * 
        CASE 
            WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN Flag IS NULL THEN 0 
                    ELSE 1 
                END
            ELSE 1
        END,
    Number,
    CASE WHEN Flag IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The idea is to put the rows with `Status = 'Closed'` and `FLAG IS NULL` directly below the rows with `Status = 'Open'`. Then rows where `FLAG IS NOT NULL` and `Status = 'Closed'` will be ordered last.

Comment: Same issue with vkp's answer. It all works with the exception of the 3rd requirement. The Flag column isn't ordering the values so that null values are on the bottom and everything else is at the top.