# SQL Query not Working on ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Table that I'm trying to query and order the return. I am able to query just fine and the SQL Statement that I'm using is also working with the exception of the last ORDER BY statement that I need to execute. The sort order is as follows:

1. Sort the Status column so that 'open' is on top, 'closed' on bottom
2. Order the 'Flag' column so that empty (null) values are on bottom (above Status = Closed) and values on top
3. Order the results of items 1 and 2 by the Number column

**Here is an example of the raw data:**

```
| Flag | Number | Status |
|------------------------|
| a    |    1   |  open  |
|      |    5   |  open  |
|      |    3   | closed |
| a    |    4   |  open  |
| a    |    2   | closed |
```

**Here is what I'm going for:**

```
| Flag | Number | Status |
|------------------------|
|  a   |    1   |  open  |
|  a   |    4   |  open  |
|      |    5   |  open  |
|  a   |    2   | closed |
|      |    3   | closed |
```

The query statement that I'm using is as follows:

```
sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Questions 
    WHERE Identifier = @identifier 
    AND Flag <> 'DELETED' 
    ORDER BY Status DESC
    , (CASE WHEN Flag is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC
    , Flag DESC
    , [Number] * 1 ASC";
```

Now, everything works fine, but the 3rd item above (sorting by Number column) doesn't work. Any ideas why?

What I'm currently getting:

```
| Flag | Number | Status |
|------------------------|
|  a   |    4   |  open  | <-- Out of order. Should be below the next record
|  a   |    1   |  open  | <-- Out of order. Should be one record up
|      |    5   |  open  | <-- OK
|      |    6   |  open  | <-- OK
|      |    3   | closed | <-- OK
|  a   |    2   | closed | <-- OK
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful input. I have tried fiddling with the query in SSMS but no luck.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: SQL Server. By the way, you solved this exact query in a different thread for me. It's just the last portion that isn't working (RE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597701/sql-query-to-order-by-on-3-different-columns)

Comment: will look into it..i see the correct results in fiddle i just set up..strange..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/492fe/1

Comment: Could it be that when I say `null` the real value is just an empty string?

Comment: that may be true..see the results with empty string. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7cca/1

Comment: I misread. I updated the question. The issue is that the 'Flagged' items (where flagged is not blank) are not ordering correctly by number. But it still works fine in the SQL Fiddler.... however in SSMS, I see bad results too.

Comment: Above you were asking if it's sql server or mysql. I'm using the godaddy default DB and I was under the assuming it was sql server but am wondering if that matters in this context. Maybe it's mysql instead?

Comment: did you check the latest fiddle i posted? i get the correct result.

Comment: afaik, it shouldn't matter as you are not using db specific functions here.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the table in SSMS. Note that QNumber is sorted by 4, 9, 6. It should be 4, 6, 9. According to my query, the output looks incorrect.

Comment: I think it's the lower- vs uppercase characters. Try sorting on `lower(Flag)` as the third sort expression.

Comment: did you change the `flag is null` in `case` to `flag = ''`?

Comment: The case is the reason that row 2 sorts before row 3.

Comment: "Note that QNumber is sorted by 4, 9, 6", Then remove `Flag DESC` from the order by. Each of 4, 9, & 6 are ordered by their flag field first.

Comment: It just reverses the order. It needs to be 4, 6, 9.

Comment: What reverses which order?

Comment: I stand corrected. I only removed `DESC`. Removing `Flag DESC` worked. I'll mark as answer if you create an answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third sort expression is on `Flag`. Those values are being sorted alphabetically before the `QNumber` sort applies. And note that case matters in the ordering as well.

Here's how I would write it:

```
ORDER BY
    Status DESC, -- might be better to use a case expression
    CASE WHEN Flag IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    QNumber
```

Since your data in the examples contradicts the data in the screenshot, it's not clear whether you needed to remove the third sort column entirely or just sort by ignoring the case of the text.

Comment: Tried applying LOWER(Flag) in both places. Still the same result.

Comment: I think that what you really wanted was to take it out entirely.

Comment: `case matters in the ordering` Not always, it depends on the collation used for ordering.

Comment: Tried applying the same fix to vkp's fiddle and it does not work.

Comment: @Alejandro The case is the reason that row 2 sorts before row 3.

Comment: @mwilson The fiddle has values for Flag that don't reflect the actual values in your real data which doesn't have ties. –  shawnt00